# ListView Long Click Animation

Tags: android, listview, animation, long-click

I would like to capture long click events in a ListView, which was easily done using a OnItemLongClickListener. However, that lacks the fading animation of the selector transitioning to a long press that is seen when the long click is handled by onCreateContextMenu. How can I get that animation using `OnItemLongClickListener`?

Comment: I had the same problem.
This answer helped me a lot. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833844/why-does-calling-setbackgroundcolor-on-a-view-break-its-long-click-color-change/6945791#6945791?newreg=f1cc9feb32c84863a4a8ac1bf75253e6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same problem and resolved it by ***removing*** the following property in the LinearLayout for my rows:

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Removing that property or setting the value to false both fixed the problem.

Comment: Indeed it does not.  Why would it?
All that happens is that the long-click stops working, as you'd expect.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the enclosing list item's view specifies:

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```