# Why does calling setBackgroundColor on a view break its long click color change and highlighting?

Tags: android, listview, view

In Android, by default when you long click on a list item, it goes from the highlight color to white indicating that the user has held it down and a context item will be displayed. Also, you can use the trackball (or arrow buttons on some phones) to select list items rather then using your fingers.

However, I have a ListView whose item's views I am calling setBackgroundColor on, and both of those expected behaviors no longer work. Anybody know why this is and how to fix it?

Notes: Setting the background color in the xml is not an option because I need to be able to set/change the color dynamically.

The code for my newView function is as follows:

```
@Override
public View newView(Context ctx, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View view = new View(mCtx);
    final LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) mCtx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = li.inflate(R.layout.task_list_item, null);

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Just a side note, but the first line in your `newView()` method is unnecessary. Delete it and use `View view = li.inflate(...)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default, `ListView` has a `Selector` that will play a `TransitionDrawable` when you longpress a list item.  However, if your list item view has a solid background, then you won't be able to see the selector's longpress animation (or on any other states) , because it's covered up by the list item's background.

If you want to see the selector's longpress animation/selected/pressed state, then the list item's has to have a transparent background when the item is selected/pressed/longpressed.  You can do it by using a [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html) as your item's background instead of a solid color.

Here is a sample of [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html) for that purpose:

```
public class ColorfulListItemDrawable extends StateListDrawable {
    private final PaintDrawable mColor;

    public ColorfulListItemDrawable(int color) {
        mColor = new PaintDrawable(color);
        initialize();
    }
    private void initialize() {
        Drawable color = mColor;
        Drawable selected = new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed, android.R.attr.state_enabled, 
                android.R.attr.state_window_focused}, selected);
        addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed, android.R.attr.state_enabled, 
                android.R.attr.state_window_focused,android.R.attr.state_selected}, selected);
        addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_enabled,android.R.attr.state_window_focused, android.R.attr.state_selected}, selected);
        addState(new int[] {}, color);
    }
    public void setColor(int color) {
        mColor.getPaint().setColor(color);
        mColor.invalidateSelf();
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 5):

When you set the background color, you're overriding the default background, which seems to be a color animation. If you want a different color, you'll have to create the animation with the color you want.

Comment: But it works fine if I set the background to something other then the default through the xml. Why should calling the setBackgroundColor break all of the other stuff when android:background does not?

Comment: Is this using a `ArrayAdapter`? I suspect that when you do it in XML, the animation gets applied to the current background when the list item is inflated in the adapter. When you use `setBackgroundColor()` you're overriding whatever animation was applied by the adapter.

Comment: Its a cursor adapter that I wrote. In either case I dont do any fancy setting of stuff. I have a line of code that sets the background color using setBackgroundColor() and when I call it, the selection stuff breaks, when I don't it doesn't.

Comment: Are you manually inflating your view or are you using the super method in `getView(...)` to get a handle on the current view?

Comment: I am overriding bindView and newView. In new view, I inflate the view using my defined xml. In bindView I set all of the view's children's formatting. This is also where I set the view's background.

Comment: Speculation, but I think somewhere after you create the view and before a view has been bound the adapter sets that animation up. is it possible to set the background in `newView()`, or can you at least move it to there to see if my theory is correct?

Comment: I tried this out to test your theory, and the same issue exists in either case.

Comment: No code for `getView()`, as I only override `bindView()` and `newView()`. See answer for `newView()` code.

Comment: Sorry meant bindView() instead of getView()

Comment: All my bindView does is set the visibility status of a few of the text/image views as well as set text on a few fields and sets background color on the View that gets passed into the function. I'd rather not post that code though.

Answer (score 3):

You want to create a `Selector` that deals with the Selected state.

As you can't use an XML solution, you want to create a [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html) programmatically and set it with `ListView.setSelector`.

Comment: Is there a default StateListDrawable one available somewhere in Android? I know that some phones use blue to select and some orange or green, and I would like my app to stick to the colors the user is used to as much as I can.

Comment: The default is `@android:drawable/list_selector_background`, I think.

Comment: I tried this, using the default selector and the same issue exists.

Answer (score 1):

This probably is happening because you are just setting single color to the layout.. where as by default it has something like `stateList` and it has different colors for different state (clicked, focussed, lingClicked) etc... you can create one and use it to set the backGround...

Answer (score 0):

I have a one line solution if you're using ListView (it probably works on all views), in your ListView code, add `android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"`.

For example:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listID"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    ...
/>
```