# ListView no longer animates on long click?

Tags: android, listview, animation

[This has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1840721/listview-long-click-animation) but without an answer that works for me (and apparently one other given the comment on the accepted/only answer).

I have a `ListView` and I've implemented a long-press-to-copy for each item in the list. I'm filling in the list with my own adapter that sets the `OnLongClickListener` and it's functioning fine except that when I touch and hold on an item, it doesn't highlight at all and doesn't fade. I haven't set any events on the `ListView` and no other events on the `View` I return from my Adapter.

I've read about several fixes like not using `wrap_content`, setting clickable to false or removing it entirely from XML. Nothing has had an impact. I have noticed that if I remove my Long Click Listener that it will animate a click, but not a fading long click.

What can I do to preserve the long click fading animation on my ListView items?

FYI: the app is targeting Gingerbread (2.3.3)

EDIT:

I'm writing a simple hash calculator. It has one activity as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Input"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text">
        <requestFocus/>
    </EditText>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Hash"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/Input"
        android:onClick="StartHashes"
        android:text="@string/HashButtonText"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/HashList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/Hash">
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Relevant code from my onCreate method:

```
    Adapter = new HashEntryAdapter(this, Entries);// Entries is Vector<HashEntry>
    ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.HashList);
    list.setAdapter(Adapter);
```

`HashEntry` is simply a class containing 2 strings: the name of the hash and the resulting output of the hash called `Name` and `Value` respectively. The `HashEntryAdapter` is as follows:

```
public class HashEntryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HashEntry> {

    private Context context;

    public HashEntryAdapter(Context context, List<HashEntry> objects) {
        super(context, R.layout.hashitem, objects);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //data from your adapter
        HashEntry entry = getItem(position);
        //we want to reuse already constructed row views...
        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.hashitem, null);
            convertView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    HashEntry entry = (HashEntry)v.getTag();
                    ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                    clipboard.setText(entry.Value);
                    Toast.makeText(context, entry.Name + " copied to clipboard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
        convertView.setTag(entry);

        TextView Name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.HashName);
        TextView Value = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.HashValue);

        Name.setText(entry.Name);
        Value.setText(entry.Value);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

And finally, hashitem.xml, a simple layout to put a grayed hash name over a black hash value:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/HashName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/HashNameFiller"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/DarkGray"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/HashValue"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/HashName"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/HashValueFiller"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

OnCreateContextMenu for vikki:

```
    list.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(new OnCreateContextMenuListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: "Frozen Yogurt" (FroYo) is Android 2.2, not 2.3.3.

Comment: Whoops... I know I targeted 2.3.3, I just slipped for a bit on what name went with it. Edited to say Gingerbread.

Comment: You could just use `onCreateContextMenu` like the stock messaging app does in ICS when you want to delete a conversation thread. You can get the `id` and `position` just like in `onLongClickListener` if you cast `ContextMenuInfo` to `AdapterContextMenuInfo`

Comment: @vikki: it functions the same but still no animation.

Comment: Set the `OnCreateContextMenuListener` on the listview and not on the individual views, like `listView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(...)`

Comment: @vikki, The animation is back but now I don't get an ID or position of the touched list entry.

Comment: post your `OnCreateContextMenuListener`

Comment: @vikki: it's empty because none of the parameters appear to have any information about which list element in the original listview was selected. But I added it anyway.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn i've added what you'll need in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use onCreateContextMenu like the stock messaging app does in ICS when you want to delete a conversation thread. You can get the id and position just like in onLongClickListener if you cast ContextMenuInfo to AdapterContextMenuInfo

```
import android.widget.AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo

...

list.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(new OnCreateContextMenuListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        AdapterContextMenuInfo contextInfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
        int position = contextInfo.position;
        long id = contextInfo.id;
        // the child view who's info we're viewing (should be equal to v)
        View view = contextInfo.targetView;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, sorry it took so long for me to get what you're saying. 5 days ago you put this in a comment. Works great!

Comment: I don't know you could have been. I think I was a little too caught up on the fact that I'm not actually creating a context menu. I was quick to overlook the answer.

Answer (score 0):

set the onlongclicklistener on the listview, set it on the listview that you declare, outside of your adapter

so instead of each cell in your adapter having an onlongclicklistener, you listview does instead

```
listview.setOnLongClickListener(){new OnLongClickListener....
```

Comment: I don't know why, but the event never actually fires. For a test I threw in a Toast message and it never appears. The animation works again though.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn post your code, the places where you declare the listview, the xml, and the place where you set up your adapter

Comment: I was hoping it's a common enough problem that I wouldn't have to, but I did.